# Can I gameshare a game that was gifted to me?

Tags: xbox-one

I am currently gamesharing with a friend of mine, If I was gifted a game by someone else, would my friend also get that game?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will own that game so your friend would be able to play it. Even if he is the gifter.